# Open inviter Symfony2- artseld/openinviter-bundle

Tags: symfony, bundle, composer-php, symfony-2.2

https://github.com/artseld/ArtseldOpeninviterBundle

I cant install this bundle in my symfony 2.2.

Problem 1
    - The requested package artseld/openinviter-bundle could not be found in any version, there may be a typo in the package name.

Potential causes:
 - A typo in the package name
 - The package is not available in a stable-enough version according to your minimum-stability setting
   see https://groups.google.com/d/topic/composer-dev/_g3ASeIFlrc/discussion for more details.

Anybody knows what is a problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This bundle does not exist in [packagist](https://packagist.org/) yet.

So you will have to use [git submodules](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Submodules) instead:

```
git submodule add http://github.com/artseld/ArtseldOpeninviterBundle.git vendor/artseld/OpeninviterBundle
```

Alternatively, it could be a good idea to ask the maintainer of the repo to support installation via composer and add the bundle to [packagist](https://packagist.org/). You could potentially request this feature by [opening an issue](https://github.com/artseld/ArtseldOpeninviterBundle/issues) in the repo directly.